# How to open/parse .wsp files in python?

Tags: graphite, graphite-carbon

I am using Graphite to listen to various temperature sensors and to plot them on the web-app. The data is stored is a .wsp (whisper) format.

Is it possible to open and parse that .wsp format? Ideally with python?

I know that graphite can plot everything, but the whisper database is useful as it combines all the data together in a single location, so it'd be ideal to read the data from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually solved this on my own.

When downloading graphite, several python files are also downloaded. This includes `whisper-fetch.py` that, in my case, is in `/usr/bin`. This imports `whisper` and outputs, among others, a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

There are some "specialized" scripts to do that, graphite creates those files by default so You can use:

- whisper-dump.py to dump the metadata about a whisper file to stdout.
- whisper-fetch.py to fetch all the metrics stored in a whisper file to stdout.

I found them in my local machine into:
./usr/local/bin/

check this for more information: https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper

Comment: Yes this is what I found as well, see my own answer above.